# i am having trouble retrieving the database id of an item that is clicked on a list

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    addBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    itemInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemInput);

    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            addItem(itemInput.getText().toString());
            itemInput.setText("");
        }
    });

    handler = new MyDbHandler(this,null,null,1);

    mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mylist.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {

            Log.d("Clicked item id", " "+position);

        }

    });
    getList();

}
```

Above is my main Activity, after looking around i found a solution that said the position parameter represents my items id in the database but that didn't work for me. I would like to get the database id of the item that is clicked on my list.

```
package com.lagfvu.quicklist;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by musaddiq on 2/23/16.
 */
public class MyDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quicklist.db";
    private static final String ITEMS_TABLE = "list";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "itemname";


    public MyDbHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE "+ ITEMS_TABLE + "(" + COLUMN_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_NAME +" TEXT"+");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ ITEMS_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void addItem(String item)
    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME,item);
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(ITEMS_TABLE, null, cv);
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteItem(long id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + ITEMS_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "=\"" + id + "\";");
    }

    //print out as string

    public ArrayList<String> DbToList()
    {
        ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();


        String query = "SELECT "+ COLUMN_NAME +" FROM "+ ITEMS_TABLE + "\n";

        //cursor pointer
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

        //move to first row in results
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("itemname"))!= null)
            {
                itemList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("itemname")));
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        db.close();
        return itemList;
    }
}
```

This is my dbhandler class.

Comment: Post the code of MyDbHandler.java class

Comment: what method you use to fetch data from database in MyDbHandler class.

Comment: @UsmanAsghar i have added the code. I am able to get all my items from my db. the issue is getting the id of the clicked item from the list so i can delete it from the db

Comment: i have a getlist method defined to get make my list

Comment: You are thinking _id is the same as the position of the listview.It is not correct because _id(primary_key auto increment) is not always increment by 1.Or when you delete an item from database table then it is correct that  all positions of listview items are in sequence but _id does not remain in same sequence.

Comment: There is not getlist method in MyDbHandler class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not any method in MyDbHandler class to get the data. 
To get Data from database.
Paste that code in MyDbHandler.java class.

---

```
public Cursor fetchAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase mDb = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(ITEMS_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME},
                null, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
```

Get specific item _id with the help of Cursor.

paste that code in MainActivity.java

---

```
MyDbHandler handler = new MyDbHandler(this,"quicklist.db",null,1);

  ListView  mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mylist.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
           Cursor cursor=handler.fetchAllData();
          cursor.moveToPosition(position);
           String _id=cursors.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
           Log.d("Clicked item id", " "+_id);

        }
});
```

Comment: and why not to just use the last parameter of `onItemClick`?

Comment: My concept was  not clear before because I think  last two parameters have same functionality  in all type of adapters. But know i have known that we can use the last parameter with simplecursoradapter to get the row id.

Comment: great! this is what `long id` is for

Answer (score 1):

I used something similar in my application, I a custom cursor adapter that used check boxes and once check it will display the row_id, the cursor is used to make a call to the database for the relevant information and then row dependant the id is displayed. May not be the best way but Im sure you could twist it around to suit your needs, hope it helps

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

private Context mContext;
private Context appContext;
private int layout;
private Cursor cr;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.layout = layout;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.cr = c;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
    CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
    int columnvalue = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
    checkBox1.setTag(columnvalue);

}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        int id = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The id is " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

}